# Formatting XML in TSQL FOR XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following TSQL code is designed to emit data in XML Format.  The following code:

```
SELECT l.wlst_Name [Name]
     , pid.wpid_Number AS [Value]
     , pid.wpid_IsPrimary AS [IsPrimary]
FROM dbo.tb_W_PhoneInternetData AS pid
        INNER JOIN dbo.tb_W_Lists AS l ON pid.wpid_wlst_Type_fk = l.wlst_pk
ORDER BY l.wlst_Name, pid.wpid_IsPrimary DESC
FOR XML RAW('Data'),TYPE
```

returns the following data, which is OK.... however

```
<Data Name="Email" Value="kevin@myemail.com" IsPrimary="1" />
<Data Name="Fax" Value="21950121" IsPrimary="1" />
<Data Name="ID Number" Value="123435456m" IsPrimary="0" />
<Data Name="Mobile" Value="99977500" IsPrimary="1" />
<Data Name="Phone" Value="23977500" IsPrimary="1" />
<Data Name="Tax No" Value="737 0443 41" IsPrimary="0" />
<Data Name="Website" Value="asdf" IsPrimary="0" />
```

....but I need it the following format:

```
<Data Name="Email" IsPrimary="1">kevin@myemail.com</Data>
<Data Name="Fax" IsPrimary="1" >21950121</Data>
<Data Name="ID Number" IsPrimary="0" />123435456m</Data>
<Data Name="Mobile" IsPrimary="1" >99977500</Data>
<Data Name="Phone" IsPrimary="1" >23977500</Data>
<Data Name="Tax No" IsPrimary="0" >737 0443 41</Data>
<Data Name="Website" IsPrimary="0" >asdf</Data>
```

? What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `@marc_s` wrote - use `FOR XML PATH`. To get exactly result you may try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #test(
    Name        VARCHAR(10),
    Value       VARCHAR(100),
    IsPrimary   BIT
)

INSERT INTO #test (Name, Value, IsPrimary) VALUES
('Email', 'kevin@myemail.com', 1),
('Fax', '21950121', 1),
('ID Number', '123435456m', 0),
('Mobile', '99977500', 1),
('Phone', '23977500', 1),
('Tax No', '737 0443 41', 0),
('Website', 'asdf', 0)


SELECT
    'Data/@Name'        = Name,
    'Data/@IsPrimary'   = IsPrimary,
    'Data'              = Value
FROM #test
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('All'), TYPE

DROP TABLE #test

-- Result
<All>
  <Data Name="Email" IsPrimary="1">kevin@myemail.com</Data>
  <Data Name="Fax" IsPrimary="1">21950121</Data>
  <Data Name="ID Number" IsPrimary="0">123435456m</Data>
  <Data Name="Mobile" IsPrimary="1">99977500</Data>
  <Data Name="Phone" IsPrimary="1">23977500</Data>
  <Data Name="Tax No" IsPrimary="0">737 0443 41</Data>
  <Data Name="Website" IsPrimary="0">asdf</Data>
</All>
```

**UPDATE:** `@Mikael Eriksson` [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000449/formatting-xml-in-tsql-for-xml#comment38872410_25000815) star wildcard. Another version below:

```
SELECT
    '@Name'        = Name,
    '@IsPrimary'   = IsPrimary,
    '*'             = Value
FROM #test
FOR XML PATH('Data'), ROOT('All'), TYPE
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with `FOR XML PATH` - something like this:

```
SELECT 
    l.wlst_Name AS '@Name',
    pid.wpid_IsPrimary AS '@IsPrimary',
    pid.wpid_Number AS 'text()'
FROM   
    dbo.tb_W_PhoneInternetData AS pid
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tb_W_Lists AS l ON pid.wpid_wlst_Type_fk = l.wlst_pk
ORDER BY 
    l.wlst_Name, pid.wpid_IsPrimary DESC
FOR XML PATH('Data'), ROOT('AllData')
```

Basically, what you want to use as attributes needs to be selected with a column alias that starts with a `@` sign.

**Update:** I updated my response - what I had been looking for (and not able to find right away) is the `... AS 'text()'` which basically produces the same output (value of the column is output as literal text - without any XML element open/end tags around it) as the "wildcard" character that @MikaelEriksson mentioned.

Comment: +1 - OP had `TYPE` in his XML declaration too, not sure if it's a requirement for him.

Comment: It will show sth like `<Data Name="..." IsPrimary="..."><wpid_Number>...</wpid_Number></Data>`

Comment: @BartekR Use the wildcard alias on wpid_number. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500154.aspx

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson Thanks, I wasn't aware of this wildcard. I'll update the answer